# Set lifecycle rules based on last accessed in Azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, retention

Is it possible to natively set a life cycle policy to delete files not accessed since X-days? If not, is there a possible to use the blob API for that?

PS: I don't mind whether to use v2 data lake or regular blob storage

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.
Have a look at the `daysAfterLastAccessTimeGreaterThan` Action run condition. Please be advised that if last access time tracking is not enabled, `daysAfterLastAccessTimeGreaterThan` uses the date the lifecycle policy was *enabled* instead of the `LastAccessTime` property of the blob. This date is also used when the `LastAccessTime` property is a `null` value.

For more information, see [Optimize costs by automatically managing the data lifecycle - Move data based on last accessed time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview#move-data-based-on-last-accessed-time).